# Deserialize LLVM Type

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

Is there a way to deserialize a type from llvm, i.e. `i32` and get back a `llvm::Type*`?

As in something like this:

```
std::string llstring = "i32*";

llvm::Type* lltype = xxxxxxx(llstring);
```

Because the LLVM types are pretty simple, it would be pretty easy to write my own, but I know one has to exist because tools like `llvm-as` exist, and that clearly has to parse types.

I have done some digging into the parsing code, and it doens't seem like it is easy to use their parser because you need to construct a llvm::LLLex class first from what I can see. It seems the parser that is used when loading `.ll.` source files is [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/LLParser_8cpp_source.html#l01800). This is quite embedded in their code as far as I can see, and is in private files that aren't accessible (not in the include dir).

One hack that would work would be generating some IR with that function and parsing it and getting types from that like this:

```
std::string IR = "@G = external global " + llstring;
auto module = llvm::parseAssemblyString(IR, ...);
llvm::Type* lltype = llvm::getNamedValue("G")->getType();
```

Is there something I am missing? If they provide [a `print` function](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Type.html#a8ac649157866dbbcfa8ea54f521c5560) in `llvm::Type`, it seems a logical next thing to have is a basic built-in type parser because this is not context dependent (from what I understand).

Comment: There's `llvm::parseType`, but it was added pretty recently ([March 7](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/commit/2ba0323e)).

Comment: Okay so I should stick with this for now, until the next release (if it makes it in)?